# Get children attributes in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Given

```xml
<mytag class="red">
     <mysubtag id="3"></mysubtag>
</mysubtag>
```

subtag might have different meanings depending on the parent tag (it might be mytag or mysupercustomtag). I have directives for all parent tags.
How can I access the subtags?

I know in the link function of the directive for mytag I can use `children()`, `contents()`, and `data()`, and even `elm.find('#someid')`. Would something like the following do the trick? What's the correct way of doing that? nested directives?

```js
.directive('mytag', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        // get the id of the first child (for example mysubtag)
        var newid = element.children()[0].getAttribute('id');
        // and put it in mytag, so that it is transformed into <div class="red" id="3">..
        attrs.$set('id', newid);
    }
  } 
})
```

Comment: I think as per angularjs, parents are not suppose to know about children

Comment: By the time the linking function runs, `mysubtag` is gone, since your directive has a template and uses `replace: true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach is not correct . For Nested directives you have to declare controller in parent directive and use require attribute in child directive to access parent controller.Please see below example from angular documentation for child parent directives.
Below link will help you to set up one

http://angularjs.org/#create-components

Comment: thanks, I got some ideas from that and I solved a simmilar problem. however, how can I have a directive require another from a different module? I'm getting "no controller nameHere" errors in firebug